# how to check count for records of current date in sql

Tags: database

I want to check the records of the current date from my files, that are updating on daily basis, how many records are processed on a particular day, want to check count.

I used this query but unfortunately no expected result found:

```
Select count(*) from invoiceitems_ip  
where billingsessionid_fk=3202 and created like '2017-11-29 00:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have billingsessionid_fk as 3202 in every row?

Comment: Its a column name (BillingSessionid)

Comment: is the value 3202 the same in every row of the record

Comment: Because if it varies, it will possibly filter out the desired records. I dont know, but I think you really want to filter with the date only

Comment: yes i want to filter with  the date only for all those records for which  the billingSessionId is 3202

Comment: I think it should be like this:
Select count(*) from my_loans where lsupdate like '2017-11-28 00:00:00'.
without that "000"

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM invoiceitems_ip
WHERE 'billingsessionid_fk' = 3202 and str_to_date(created, '%d-%m-%Y') = curdate();
```

Please comment for further help.

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 8
'str_to_date' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: That's strange, because that has worked for me for most of the times. Please try replacing str_to_date(created, '%d-%m-%Y') by date(created)

Comment: Or you have another option WHERE 'billingsessionid_fk' = 3202 and created = curdate();